# Webpage zoom in when i click on input, button or other controls

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, viewport

I am facing simple issue with a bootstrap theme. It works fine on all browsers expect ios safari browsers.

When even i click on any input field or button it just zoom in the page.

Shall i use following to block the auto zoom option 
`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />`

or there is any other way of doing it, as i noticed sometime using these option breaks the design in certain cases.

Comment: This meta tag **should not** break bootstrap's design in any way. I'm still not sure what you're trying to do though.

Comment: Not in bootstrap, it was a custom responsive them which i had issue alsong with asp.net webform..

Comment: Again, what's going wrong exactly? when you click on an input the page zooms in on all devices **BUT** safari?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html + https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

Answer (score 0):

i think you can better use

```
 transform: scale(1.5);
```

on the body for example